# Turning 1d array into 2d

Tags: java, data-structures

I am working on an assignment for my java class and part of the assignment requires reading in a .csv file that is 20x20 and inserting each string into an array.

I am trying to convert my 1d array from the initial reading in of the file into a 2d array, but I seem to be doing something wrong in my output of the data.

I made an add method, and when running the program and calling the method I only get one column of strings and listed in reverse order, but if I do a `System.out.println()` I don't the output I desire. I am still fairly new to this so I'm sure I just don't see the simple error, but to me, it looks correct.

the reading in of the file

```
try {
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(toOpen);    
    while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
        fromFile = fileScanner.nextLine();
        String temp[] = fromFile.split(" ");
        theList.add(temp[0]);
        System.out.println(fromFile);
        String[][] arr = new String[20][20];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = temp[i];
                System.out.print(arr);
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    fileScanner.close();
```

my add method

```
public void add(String tableValue) { // Adds a new node
    Node newNode = new Node(tableValue);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        setRoot(newNode);
    } else {
        newNode.setNext(getRoot());
        setRoot(newNode);
    }
}
```

and my method that prints the result

```
public String makeString() { // A Class that makes a string
    String theString = new String();

    if (isEmpty()) {
        theString = "List is empty";
    } else {
        Node printer = getRoot();

        while (printer != null) {
            theString += printer.getTableValue() + " ";
            printer = printer.getNext();
        }
    }

    return theString;
}
```

Comment: Update: I put another sentence into may answer, guess that will help with *printing* array content. Beyond that: please give feedback about the answers you got. It is not exactly polite to drop content and then vanish in thin air. You could *accept* the "most helpful" answer at some point for example.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your problem is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    arr[i][j] = temp[i];
```

This assigns the **same** value (temp[i]) to all slots in arr[i]. Again guessing, I think you need something like:

```
int tmpIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    arr[i][j] = temp[tmpIndex];
    tmpIndex++;
```

In other words: you have 400 different values in temp. But your code is only assigning the first 20 values 20 times again and again.

Beyond that: `System.out.print(arr);` isn't doing what you expect it to do - to learn how to print **arrays** correctly, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array).

Answer (score 1):

As we don't know the number of lines in a file, we can start by storing each line into an `ArrayList` (of `String[]`) and then convert it into a 2D array, e.g.:

```
List<String[]> lines = new ArrayList<>();
while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
    String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
    String temp[] = line.split(" ");
    lines.add(temp);
}
```

Now, convert it into an array:

```
String[][] array = new String[lines.size()][];
for(int i=0 ; i<lines.size() ; i++){
    array[i] = lines.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Don't iterate over the list just use `Collection::toArray` with `String[][] strings = lines.toArray(new String[theList.size()][]);`

Answer (score 0):

I hevent seen where you have really used your **add** and **makeString** methods, and what is the role of the **theList** variable.

Also, could you please send your file Content.

any way:

If this is your calling to the **add** method: `theList.add(temp[0]);` that means that you are inside an ***Extended class structure*** that you have not shown it. but Any way you ***have not used*** it to fill the 2d Array in the **for loop**

the Code here is also error: you insert the same element **temp[i]** in every line !!!!

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = temp[i];
                System.out.print(arr);
            }
        }
```

You can use a dynamic structure like **ArrayList** to fill the Elements...